# How do I discover which trait from_str_radix() belongs to?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to use [from_str_radix()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=from_str_radix) in a generic function.

This function is [implemented in a macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#1067).

I successfully use the bound `T: std::str::FromStr` to give me `str::parse::<T>` but I do not know how to find out which trait `from_str_radix()` belongs to.

What is the method, for finding out which trait an arbitrary function (implemented across many integer types) belongs to?

Comment: I don't think there is any trait unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not belong to any trait.

If you need it in a trait for a generic bound, you can use [`num_traits::Num`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/trait.Num.html#tymethod.from_str_radix).

Comment: I've added that crate and bound and now `T::from_str_radix("CAFE", 16);` compiles.  Does `num_traits` retrospectively create traits which were missing for numbers in the core of the language?  i.e. There appear to be functions like `from_str_radix()` which exist across many numeric types, but which are not part of a trait and so could not be used in generics before num_traits.

Comment: @fadedbee It just create the trait and implement it for the types.